# CSS not dynamically updating in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-style

I'm trying to make 2 div's with their width set by an angularJS value (0 - 100) so I did this:

```
<span class="green" ng-style="{width: '{{videoRating}}%'}"</span>
<span class="red" ng-style="{width: '{{100-videoRating}}%'}"></span>
```

but the width is calculated on the initial value of videoRating. When I change that value, it won't update the style.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I tried adding `ng-cloak` and `$scope.$apply()` but no luck

Comment: Please share the code where you are updating the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ng-style should not use `{{}}` interpolation directive, you could use direct scope variables there.

**Markup**

```
<span class="green" ng-style="{width: videoRating + '%'}"</span>
<span class="red" ng-style="{width: (100 - videoRating) + '%'}"></span>
```

Comment: The contents of an ng-style are (key,value) pairs such that the value is a "truthy" expression